# Getting 2 columns as a result, only want one specifically

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, xml-import

With the following piece of Importxml I'm getting two columns, one is empty and the other one is filled with data that I want.

```
=importxml("http://www.runeclan.com/clan/Ultimate_Despair/members?sort_by=name&order=asc","//*[contains(@class, 'clan_rank')]")
```

Is there a possiblity that I can only get the second one? I've tried the following, but it didn't work since it's one element.

```
=importxml("http://www.runeclan.com/clan/Ultimate_Despair/members?sort_by=name&order=asc","//*[contains(@class, 'clan_rank')][2]")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=INDEX(importxml("http://www.runeclan.com/clan/Ultimate_Despair/members?sort_by=name&order=asc","//*[contains(@class, 'clan_rank')]"),1,2)
```

Comment: Updated with the "2" ... my understanding of index is you don't need to put a blank a you did with `,,2` as it will default to `1` ... so I included it for clarity

Comment: It's not working as I would like to see. It only shows one record now instead of the usual 25. It did fix the column problem though! Tried the suggestion above with ",,2" and that helped. Thank you both very much!